# User token between web pages

Tags: asp.net, web

I'm getting started developing web applications(using ASP.NET Web Api for the server side).
I'm writing a simple web site for practice and I'm currently handling user login issues.
I'm not dealing with security issues right now, my question is much more simple.

My question is this:

Let's say that a user login process was succesfull and now I want to allow the user to access pages only registered user can but I don't want the user to repeat the login process each time he passes from one page to another.

What's the term for that ability? token? session?

Comment: How are you handling the authentication? Are you using Identity or SimpleMembership?

Comment: I simply send a string and if that string is muUser(if userInput == "myUser") then it's authenticated.

Comment: I believe "token" or "session id" term would apply here, yes

Comment: Rolling your own authentication is not a good idea. Stick with an existing framework and learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tokens are probably the way to go.  Here is a simple "roll your own" example of Token based authentication:

http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/